Laravel Configure Route
I am upgrading version of Lumen Laravel and going to use Laravel Framework. I have the following Route
$app->get('/{version:v1}/some_url', 'SomeController@method');
$app->get('/{version:v2}/some_url', 'SomeController@method');

I have the following Controller
class SomeController extends ParentController {
    public function method($request, $version) {
        echo $version;
    }
}

Above source code works find in Lumen. with the following command
curl -X GET localhost/v1/some_url
curl -X GET localhost/v2/some_url

But When migrating to Laravel Framework
Route::prefix('{version:v1}')->group(function(){
   Route::post('some_url', ['uses' => 'SomeController@method'])
});

Route::prefix('{version:v2}')->group(function(){
   Route::post('some_url', ['uses' => 'SomeController@method'])
});

With this, curl method does not work, getting 404
If I am writing like this
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function(){
   Route::post('some_url', ['uses' => 'SomeController@method'])
});

Route::prefix('v2')->group(function(){
   Route::post('some_url', ['uses' => 'SomeController@method'])
});

Curl command reach my method, but I cannot get the version information. How do I save myself?

Check the base URL with the prefix and also check the complete API URL in Postman. After that clear the cache.  it should work.

Figured out long time ago. but thanks @DeveloperNilesh

Welcome @Popeye ! :)
